# is it possible to reboot into Recovery Mode on OS X 10.9 without holding down Command and + R?

Tags: macos, system-recovery

I really need to reboot into the [Recovery Mode](https://www.apple.com/uk/osx/recovery/) of OS X 10.9 so that I can fix a problem flagged up by Disc Utility, however I cannot hold down the Command and R buttons myself as I am quadriplegic.  I don't have access to an able-bodied person for the next couple of days, so I can't get help to hold down the keys from that quarter.

So is it possible to enter Recovery Mode without holding down the Command and R keys on start-up?   I was wondering if there is a special flag I could use in the Terminal to enable me to reboot into that mode?

I've been Googling like mad but I can't find any other answer than "reboot whilst holding down the Command and R keys", which whilst true isn't much use to me!

Comment: If you’re able to lift objects(?), you could try using something like a heavy eraser to hold down one or both of the keys.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately I'm only able to control my head and right index finger.

Comment: I tried entering recovery mode on a VM which I tried to reach remotely from a Linux machine using VMWare VSphere. Somehow, I couldn't get it to enter recovery mode with any key combination. I could only get to boot menu. Thus I arrived at this question. I'm surprised that it's not documented anywhere and practically nobody mentions it.

Answer (score 15):

Use the following command from a terminal:

```
sudo nvram "recovery-boot-mode=unused"
```

Comment: The quotes are unnecessary. Some additional explanation would make this a better answer, including a discussion of what the `nvram` command does, what are the valid values for that variable, say something about its behavior (it is deleted after booting into Recovery), and describe what to do after running this command (e.g., run `sudo shutdown -r now`, or choose Apple > Restart).

Comment: I am running Mavericks in a VM.  After running `sudo nvram recovery-boot-mode=unused`, I had to run the command `nvram -d recovery-boot-mode` from a terminal window in Recovery mode before it would boot normally again.  Note, I did not reinstall OSX, I just wanted to reboot in Recovery mode, and then normally again.

Answer (score 4):

The other answer is incomplete & dangerous. The following would help users get into recovery mode and back out:

```
sudo nvram recovery-boot-mode=unused && sudo shutdown -r now
```

Once in recovery mode you can run the commands you need. In my case, I wanted to run `csrutil disable` in `Utilities`>`Terminal`.

Run the commands you want and then end with:

```
nvram -d recovery-boot-mode && shutdown -r now
```

And you'll get back into normal MacOS.

Comment: Thanks! You made my day! )))